# Firefox missing the string combined by "\1"

Tags: javascript

I am fixing some client's code, he combine form input value by "\1" to an hidden input and submit, this is the simple sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">send</button>
    <form name="test" id="test" method="post" action="test.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="a" value="test">
        <input type="hidden" name="b" value="123">
        <input type="hidden" name="result" id="result">
    </form>
    <script>
        var form = document.getElementById('test'),
            str = '';

        for (i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
            str += encode(form.elements[i].value + "\1";
        }

        result = str.split("\1");
        document.getElementById('result').value = (result.join("\1"));
        form.submit();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome and IE will be fine, but Firefox will only get the first value even I am sure the combined string is correct.

Because of it a big project and I am just help to fix some bugs like this, therefore I can't change too much code in case other parts of the website might get crashed, so I really need to figure out why Firefox break the value that combined by "\1".

Comment: `\{numeric value}` is an escape sequence. Mask the backslash by doubling it …

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "\1" is being replaced by "SOH" .. May be some locale language problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
        str += encode(form.elements[i].value) + "\\1";
    }
```

Comment: Have any other solution? the former programmer use \1 to split like everywhere in whole project, if I change this variable, I have revise thousands of code at the same time, and I am curious why IE and Chrome ok with that but Firebox

Comment: Well it will take some time for me to find out other solution. but did you checked that your `encode` method is missing closing bracket? May be that is a reason.